# SQL query on table A with a (multiple rows) subquery on table B and result of the query show in 1 single record

Tags: sql, rdbms

How can I come to the output of tableC in below data example by use of an SQL query by combining the data of input tableA and input tableB and showing all the order numbers in 1 single record in output tableC, based on customer_id=2

I was thinking of using an SQL query with a subquery to construct tableC, like this:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT number from tableB where customer_id=tableA.customer_id) as orders from tableA WHERE customer_id=2
```

but this this doesn't work due to the multiple rows in the subquery.

Any other ideas?

```
input tableA:

customer_id  name   
--------------------
1            name1  
2            name2  
3            name3  

input tableB:

order_id    number  customer_id
-----------------------------------------------------------
1           901     2
2           902     2
3           903     2

desired output tableC: 

customer_id name    orders
--------------------------------------------------------
2           name2   901
                    902 
                    903
```

Comment: that is not a result a resulset would produce, and you only need a simple join

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the desired output in `tableC` by using the following SQL query, which combines data from `tableA` and `tableB` for `customer_id = 2`.

```sql
SELECT 
  a.customer_id, 
  a.name, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    b.number 
    ORDER BY 
      b.order_id
  ) AS orders 
FROM 
  tableA a 
  LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id 
WHERE 
  a.customer_id = 2 
GROUP BY 
  a.customer_id, 
  a.name;
```